# Rails money column with no cents

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app where I'm asking for next year's budget request.  The `amount` field is money - but, I don't want any decimals.

I will be using the data to display with `number_to_currency`.

Should I use:

```
add_column :mytable, :amount, :decimal, :precision => 12, :scale => 0
```

Or:

```
add_column :mytable, :amount, :integer
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
add_column :mytable, :amount, :integer
```

and `number_to_currency(x/100)` or `number_to_currency(x/100, {options})`

This way you avoid any rounding issues.